# Getting parsing error setFormula Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I get parsing error after i use setFormula. i try `spreadsheetApp.flush();` and leave out the last bracket in the formula but i still get the error.
the formula is in german but it isnt wrong, if i edit it after i run the code with out the last bracket and press enter in the cell the formula is working

```
for (i=1; i<50; i++)
   {
   var k=i+1
   var formula = "=WENN(ISTFEHLER(SVERWEIS(C"+k+"&\"10\";Bonus!$P$2:$Q$595;1;FALSCH));\" \";\"Rare\")"
   Sheet.getRange(i+1,26).setFormula(formula);
   }
```

**Result**
[image: Parsing Error]

Comment: It should be `SpreadsheetApp.flush();`, not `spreadsheetApp.flush();`. Can you give a sample of what you want your formula to look like? What are you [Locale settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)? Maybe you need to change `;` to `,`.

Comment: @ziganotschka the formula in the cell should look like this `=WENN(ISTFEHLER(SVERWEIS(C3&"10";Bonus!$P$2:$Q$595;1;FALSCH));" ";"Rare")` english `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C3&"10";Bonus!$P$2:$Q$595;1;FALSE));" ";"Rare")` . My Settings: Language: German Recalculation: on change ,Iterative calculation: off

Comment: @ziganotschka `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` is not working too in my case

Comment: What are you using it for?

Comment: @ziganotschka for a online game to get data

Comment: I mean in your code. `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` should be used after a time consuming request before proceeding with a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is a bug

It has already been filed on Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/36765372) and hopefully will be solved in the future.

In the meantime, you need to implement a workaround:

- Change your Locale to USA
- Use the English version of the formula **whereby `;` need to be replaced through `,`**